# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch

Tags: java, assert, hamcrest

`Assert.assertThat(newUrl.contains("providerId="), is(true));`

why do i get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hamcrest/Description;)V
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:18)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:865)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:832)
```

Comment: well, what are you doing in `at com.waze.automation.rtsimulator.headlessclient.HeadlessClientE2ET.getAdvilUrlReturnsUrlWithPopulatedAdsInfoAndRtStateInfo(HeadlessClientE2ET.java:381)`? Is this a maven app?

Comment: @Stacktrace I don't get it. is it a syntax issue or a configuration issue?

Comment: If it compiles (and if it did not compile you would not get this error) than it is bound to be configuration problem. Wrong version/package in classpath...